# How to use external urls for product images in Magento2

Tags: image, external, magento2, imageurl

Need to display images for products without uploading on my server. I need to achieve:

- Images are uploaded on another server
- Images to be display on magento2 products

Is it possible that we add image URL attribute like: ImageURL1, ImageURL2 and import both the image URL while product upload and Call them on Magento2 Website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add additional product attributes to store custom images from other server. But in order for them to be shown in your storefront, you'll need to adapt your product page templates, asking the product for this attributes and create the images with those URLs (when not empty values there).

Additionally if you'd like to serve all your media from a different server but only changing the domain part of the URL, you can use a CDN (content delivery network), which is supported by Magento out of the box, and can set setup in the Magento admin, menu STORES > Configuration > Web, groups "Base URLs" and "Base URLs (Secure)".

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used AWS s3  for the external URL but images is not showing in the website: 
http://xyzcom/pub/media/logo/default/logo_new.png
 https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonawscom/xyzbucket/pub/media/logo/default/logo_new.png